# Como puedo saber cuál es la ruta activa en Angular?

Tags: angular

Como podría saber: 
La intención es mostrar un titulo u otro de 3 que debería mostrar.
`<a *ngIf="routerLinkActive='activo'">{{titulo}}</a>`

Comment: Es necesario que destruyas el elemento `<a>` o te sirve si sólo lo ocultas cuando no está activo?

Comment: El metodo url de Router te da la ruta activa , router importado de @angular/router

Comment: @devconcept No haría falta destruirlo, solo que si es la ruta activa mostrará algo... Pero ya lo he conseguido, gracias. Saludos.

Comment: @danit pero créeme que me costó mucho tiempo es que llevo 4 días con Angular no sé prácticamente nada.

Comment: te ha funcionado con el metodo url de router? Para poner la respuesta

Comment: @danit Al final lo hice así.   public recargar() {
    location.hash = '#/gestionCampos';
    this.ruta = location.host + location.pathname + location.hash;
    location.href = this.ruta;
    location.reload();
  } /// esto en gestion-campos.component.ts y en component de header esto. recargarPS: ProbarSimulacionComponent;
  constructor() {
    this.recargarGC = new GestionCamposComponent();}       y en el html header esto. <h2 *ngIf="gestionCampos.isActive">Gestión de Campos</h2> y con eso supe mostrar el titulo de cada ruta de las tres posibilidades que tenía.

Comment: Perfecto , te dejo un ejemplo de como funciona con router para que lo veas https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ss1a8h , al entrar en el editor a la derecha veras la web si le añades /hello a la url veras como cambia la router.url

Comment: @danit Muchísimas gracias. En serio. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes importar Router desde @angular/router.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
```

Después lo inyectas en tu constructor:

```
constructor(private router: Router ) { }
```

Después utilizas la propiedad url de Router desde cualquier método para obtener lo que estás buscando:

```
console.log(this.router.url); //  /tu-ruta
```

Comment: Esa no se porque no me funciona, pero lo he conseguido de otra forma. gracias.